# Adding text to different panels in lattice when scales are separate?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I would like to add text labels (e.g. a, b, c, d) to different panels in a lattice multi panel plot. I would like the text to appear at the same point (i.e. in the top left corner) in each plot, however I can't seem to do this when the scales are not constant.

```
library(lattice)
X <- rnorm(100)
Y <- rnorm(100)
n <- c(rep("control", 5), rep("low", 5), rep("medium", 5), 
       rep("high", 5), rep("v.high", 5))
Z <- c(rep("a", 25), rep("b", 25), rep("c", 25), rep("d", 25))

df1 <- data.frame(X, Y, n, Z)

MyText <- c("(c)", "(d)", "(a)", "(b)")

xyplot(X ~ Y|Z, data=df1,
   groups=n,
   panel=function(x, y,...){
     panel.xyplot(x, y,...)
     panel.text(-1, 1.5, labels=MyText[panel.number()]) 
   },
   ylab = expression(paste(delta, ""^"15", "N")),
   xlab = expression(paste(delta, ""^"13", "C")),
   scales=list(relation="free"), 
   strip = F,
   auto.key=list(columns= 5, title="Treatments", cex.title=1))
```

If anybody has any advice on this your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is with `grid.text`, referring to the desired location with `npc` coordinates, where the lower left corner is (0, 0), and the upper right is (1, 1).

```
library(grid)
xyplot(X~Y|Z, data=df1,
       groups=n,
       panel=function(x, y,...) {
         panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
         grid.text(MyText[panel.number()], unit(0.05, 'npc'), unit(0.95, 'npc'))
       },
       ylab = expression(paste(delta, ""^"15","N")),
       xlab = expression(paste(delta, ""^"13","C")),
       scales=list(relation="free"), 
       strip = F,
       auto.key=list(columns= 5, title="Treatments", cex.title=1))
```

[image]